# Multiple access specifies good for machine-generated code?

Tags: c++

In the second edition of "The C++ Programming Language", I read that we can have more than one private/public section of the class. However, allowing many access specifiers in a class is useful for machine-generated code?

I fail to understand how multiple specifiers are useful for machine-generated code? Can someone share deep insight to it?

Comment: You qualified below that you were quoting from "The C++ Programming Language, 2nd Edition", published in 1991.  The statement is ABSOLUTELY UNTRUE for any modern C++ compiler. I'm *including* old Microsoft, Borland or Watcom C++ compilers you might still be running from the late 1990s.  It doesn't matter if you interleave publish/private visibility sections.

Answer (score 0):

> However, allowing many access specifiers in a class is useful for machine-generated code?

To clarify: the book is referring to programs that output C++ code (rather than codegen in the sense of the quality of the generated output from the compiler).

A script that does that job is (very slightly) easier to write if, instead of having to sort members by access specifier and then output the result, you can simply write `public`/`private` as needed while you stream them out.

You could even do it for every member:

```
public:  int a;
private: int b;
public:  void f();
private: void g() { ... }
// etc.
```

which looks like other languages which have the specifier as an individual modifier of each member.

Comment: I agree that I might need to group in big classes. My question is from the c++ book where he clearly says that "However, allowing many access specifiers in a class is useful for machine-generated code". Sorry, but can not agree with just NO for that. :)

Comment: second edition of "The C++ Programming Language" by Bjarne Stroustrup. Section 10.2.8, Structures and classes.

Comment: @HemantBhargava Ah, I see what you mean now by machine-generated code (the title was missing the hyphen!). Edited the question to answer that question instead.